# Mathematical Step for consistency

Tags: least-squares, econometrics, estimators, consistency

Let me state my problem from the beginning:

Let $i$ be an index representing countries ($i = {1,2,\ldots,N }$), and $t$ represent time, denoted as available data for country $i$ ($t = {1,2,\ldots,T_i }$).
Let's consider the data-generating process(DGP) for $\Delta y_{it}$, which follows an AR(1) process:
\begin{equation}
\Delta y_{it} = \alpha_i + \rho_i y_{i,t-1} + u_{it}
\end{equation}

Then, consider the OLS estimate of country-specific persistent parameter $\hat{\rho}_i$ for country $i$ equal to:
\begin{equation}
\hat{\rho}_i =  \frac{ \sum_{t \in T_i}(\Delta y_{it} - \overline{\Delta y}_i) (y_{i,t-1} -\bar{y}_{i,-})}{\sum_{t \in T_i} (y_{i,t-1} - \bar{y}_{i,-})^2}
\end{equation}
where $\overline{\Delta y}_i= \frac{\sum_{t \in T_i} \Delta y_{it}}{T_i}$ and $\bar{y}_{i,-} = \frac{\sum_{t \in T_i} y_{i,t-1}}{T_i}$

Since the true DGP is given by the first equation, $\hat{\rho}_i$ is a consistent estimator for $\rho_i$, i.e., $plim(\hat{\rho}_i)= \rho_i$.

Now, let's consider the OLS estimate of $\rho$ from the following equation:

\begin{equation}
\Delta y_{it} = \rho y_{i,t-1} + \delta_t + u_{it}
\end{equation}
Thus, $\hat{\rho}$ reads as

\begin{equation}
\hat{\rho} = \frac{\sum_{i \in N} \sum_{t \in T_i}(\Delta y_{it} - \overline{\Delta y}) (y_{i,t-1} -\bar{y}_{-})}{\sum_{i \in N} \sum_{t \in T_i} (y_{i,t-1} - \bar{y}_{-})^2}
\end{equation}

where $\overline{\Delta y}= \frac{\sum_{i \in N} \sum_{t \in T_i} \Delta y_{it}}{\sum_{i \in N} T_i}$ and $\bar{y}_{-} = \frac{\sum_{i \in N} \sum_{t \in T_i} y_{i,t-1}}{\sum_{i \in N} T_i}$

Focusing on the numerator of $\hat{\rho}$:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{i \in N} \sum_{t \in T_i}(\Delta y_{it} - \overline{\Delta y}) (y_{i,t-1} -\bar{y}_{-}) =& \sum_{i \in N} \sum_{t \in T_i}\Delta y_{it}  (y_{i,t-1} -\bar{y}_{-}) \\
=& \sum_{i \in N} \sum_{t \in T_i}\Delta y_{it}  (y_{i,t-1} -\bar{y}_{i,-}) + \sum_{i \in N}  \sum_{t \in T_i} \overline{\Delta y}_i (\bar{y}_{i,-} - \bar{y}_{-})
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

The paper says the first equality occurs because $\sum_{t \in T_i} (y_{i,t-1} - \bar{y}_{-})=0$. Could you show me how to exploit such basic statistical result? I mean, I know that the sum of the deviations from the average is zero, but how can exploit it?

What about the second equality?

Comment: "How to exploit it" is as broad as "how do I use mathematics"?  Could you please be more specific about what you are trying to ask?

Comment: I mean, can you show me (mathematically) how to get the first and second equality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In what follows I assume that you use $\displaystyle \sum_{i \in N}$ and $\displaystyle \sum_{t \in T_i}$ and as notation for $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^N$ and $\displaystyle \sum_{t = 1}^{T_i}$, respectively.

---

- Note that
  \begin{aligned}
  \sum_{i \in N} \sum_{t \in T_i} (y_{i,t-1} -\bar{y}_{-})
  &= 
  \sum_{i \in N} \sum_{t \in T_i}  y_{i,t-1} - \sum_{i \in N} \sum_{t \in T_i} \bar{y}_{-} \\
  &=
  \sum_{i \in N} \sum_{t \in T_i}  y_{i,t-1} - 
  \sum_{i \in N} \sum_{t \in T_i} \frac{\sum_{i \in N} \sum_{t \in T_i} y_{i,t-1}}{\sum_{i \in N} T_i} \\
  &=
  \sum_{i \in N} \sum_{t \in T_i}  y_{i,t-1} -
   \frac{\sum_{i \in N} \sum_{t \in T_i} y_{i,t-1}}{\sum_{i \in N} T_i} 
  \sum_{i \in N} \sum_{t \in T_i}  1\\
  &=  
  \sum_{i \in N} \sum_{t \in T_i}  y_{i,t-1} -
   \frac{\sum_{i \in N} \sum_{t \in T_i} y_{i,t-1}}{\sum_{i \in N} T_i} 
  \sum_{i \in N} T_i \\
  &= 0.
  \end{aligned}
  Thus,
  $$
  \sum_{i \in N} \sum_{t \in T_i} \overline{\Delta y} (y_{i,t-1} -\bar{y}_{-})
  =
  \overline{\Delta y} \sum_{i \in N} \sum_{t \in T_i}  (y_{i,t-1} -\bar{y}_{-})
  =
  0,
  $$
  and the first equality follows from
  $$
  (\Delta y_{it} - \overline{\Delta y}) (y_{i,t-1} -\bar{y}_{-})
  = \Delta y_{it} (y_{i,t-1} -\bar{y}_{-}) - \overline{\Delta y} (y_{i,t-1} -\bar{y}_{-}).
  $$
- Further, observe that
  \begin{aligned}
  \sum_{i \in N}  \sum_{t \in T_i} \overline{\Delta y}_i \bar{y}_{-}
  &=
  \sum_{i \in N}  \overline{\Delta y}_i \bar{y}_{-} \sum_{t \in T_i} 1  \\
  &= 
  \sum_{i \in N}  \overline{\Delta y}_i \bar{y}_{-}  T_i \\
  &= 
  \sum_{i \in N}  \frac{\sum_{t \in T_i} \Delta y_{it}}{T_i} \bar{y}_{-}  T_i \\
  &= 
  \sum_{i \in N} \sum_{t \in T_i} \Delta y_{it} \bar{y}_{-}
  \end{aligned}
  and
  \begin{aligned}
  \sum_{i \in N}  \sum_{t \in T_i} \overline{\Delta y}_i \bar{y}_{i,-}
  &= 
  \sum_{i \in N}  \overline{\Delta y}_i \bar{y}_{i,-} \sum_{t \in T_i} 1 \\
  &=
  \sum_{i \in N}  \overline{\Delta y}_i \bar{y}_{i,-} T_i  \\
  &= 
  \sum_{i \in N}  \frac{\sum_{t \in T_i} \Delta y_{it}}{T_i} \bar{y}_{i,-} T_i \\
  &= 
  \sum_{i \in N}  \sum_{t \in T_i}  \Delta y_{it} \bar{y}_{i,-}.
  \end{aligned}
  With that, the second equality follows from
  $$
  \Delta y_{it}  (y_{i,t-1} -\bar{y}_{-}) = 
  \Delta y_{it} y_{i,t-1} - \Delta y_{it} \bar{y}_{-}
  $$
  and
  $$
  \Delta y_{it}  (y_{i,t-1} -\bar{y}_{i,-}) = \Delta y_{it} y_{i,t-1} - \Delta y_{it} \bar{y}_{i,-}, \\
  \overline{\Delta y}_i (\bar{y}_{i,-} - \bar{y}_{-}) = \overline{\Delta y}_i \bar{y}_{i,-} - \overline{\Delta y}_i \bar{y}_{-}.
  $$